# RegEx Lookaround issue

Tags: regex, powershell-2.0

I am using Powershell 2.0. I have file names like `my_file_name_01012013_111546.xls`.  I am trying to get `my_file_name.xls`.   I have tried:

> `.*(?=_.{8}_.{6})`

which returns my_file_name.  However, when I try

> `.*(?=_.{8}_.{6}).{3}`

it returns `my_file_name_01`.

I can't figure out how to get the extension (which can be any 3 characters.  The time/date part will always be _ 8 characters _ 6 characters.

I've looked at a ton of examples and tried a bunch of things, but no luck.

Comment: Are you sure you'll never have, say, `.xlsx` files and need a 4-character extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this ( not tested), but it should works for any 'my_file_name' lenght , any lenght of digit and any kind of extension.

```
"my_file_name_01012013_111546.xls" -replace '(?<=[\D_]*)(_[\d_]*)(\..*)','$2'
```

non regex solution:

```
$a = "my_file_name_01012013_111546.xls"

$a.replace( ($a.substring( ($a.LastIndexOf('.') - 16 ) , 16 )),"")
```

Comment: That works. I have no idea what the $2 does. Is that getting the extension?

Comment: @user1921849 yes, exstension is backreferenced with $2, $1 is the part with digit, the first part (non digit) isn't captured while in the look-ahead

Comment: It actually doesn't work entirely. If I have a file like "my_file_250_01012013_111546.xls" it cuts off the _250.

Comment: @user1921849 this is not a file name like in your example.. it has digit in the name part. I think you have too many different name type for using regex. Edit  your question and add all differents name kind, Any way try this: `-replace '(?<=.*_.*_.*)(_[\d_]*)(\..*)','$2'`

Comment: It looks like this works: '(?<=[\D_]*)(_[\d_]{8})(_[\d_]{6})(\..*)','$3'

Comment: I said it would always be 8 digits underscore, then 6 digits at the end before the extension.  An example is just that, not every case. The filename can have any combination, it is just the last 16 characters before the extension I want to get rid of, which now that I think of, I could have just used subtrings. Thanks for the help though. You got me on the right track.

Comment: @user1921849 have you tryed regex of my previous comment?

Comment: I've simplified it: -replace  '_[0-9]{*}_[0-9]{6}'.  There may or may not be underscores in the filename (other than the date/time). I just put them there because there may be. The user can name the report whatever they want. The report batch adds the date/time that we have to remove.

Comment: That works too..and probably was the easiest solution for someone like me that dosen't know regex well.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to find the name and extension, you probably want something like this: `^(.*)_[0-9]{8}_[0-9]{6}(\..{3})$`

`my_file_name` will be in backreference 1 and `.xls` in backreference 2.

If you want to remove everything else and return the answer, you want to substitute the "numbers" with nothing: `'my_file_name_01012013_111546.xls' -replace '_[0-9]{8}_[0-9]{6}' ''`. You can't simply pull two bits (name and extension) of the string out as one match - regex patterns match contiguous chunks only.

Answer (score 0):

The original regex you specified returns the maximum match that has 14 characters after it (you can change to (?=.{14}) who is the same).

Once you've changed it, it returns the maximum match that has 14 characters after it + the next 3 characters. This is why you're getting this result.

The approach described by Inductiveload is probably better in case you can use backreferences. I'd use the following regex: `(.*)[_\d]{16}\.(.*)` Otherwise, I'd do it in two separate stages

1. get the initial part
2. get the extension

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get `my_filename_01` when you add that is because [lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) are zero-width. This means that they do not consume characters in the string.

As you stated, `.*(?=_.{8}_.{6})` matches `my_file_name` because that string is is followed by something matching `_.{8}_.{6}`, however once that match is found, you've only consumed `my_file_name`, so the addition of `.{3}` will then consume the next 3 characters, namely `_01`.

As for a regex that would fit your needs, others have posted viable alternatives.